# What is R counterpart of Python comamnd requests.post()?

Tags: python, r

A user may know R but needs to run the following python code

```
import requests
import json

query = "asthma"
r = requests.post("https://ndar.nih.gov/api/search/nda_sw_removal/collection/full", query)

collections = json.loads(r.text)
collections
```

Using R libraries, how can the request.post call be rewritten in R?
The challenge is what python does with the `query` parameter exactly.

Comment: Look into the hhtr and Rcurl packages.  You might also search for "R http post"; I didn't get enough of a duplicate to close this ticket, but there are some useful code examples for you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html):

An example taken from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.3.1/topics/POST):

```
b2 <- "http://httpbin.org/post"
POST(b2, body = "A simple text string")
```

Another example taken from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html):

```
r <- POST("http://httpbin.org/post", body = list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
```

Based on the suggestion by Slam in comments:

Another source of reference: http://httr.r-lib.org/reference/POST.html

Comment: Probably, best source for docs is httr reference :)
http://httr.r-lib.org/reference/POST.html

Answer (score 0):

```
library(httr)
query = "asthma"
r = POST("https://ndar.nih.gov/api/search/nda_sw_removal/collection/full", body=query)
library(jsonlite)
aa<-fromJSON(content(r,'text'))
str(aa)
View(aa$collection$results)
```